# Conditional probability greater than 1?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

```
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
| Day | Outlook | Temp | Humidity | Beach? |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   1 | Sunny   | High | High     | Yes    |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   2 | Sunny   | High | Normal   | Yes    |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   3 | Sunny   | Low  | Normal   | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   4 | Sunny   | Mild | High     | Yes    |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   5 | Rain    | Mild | Normal   | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   6 | Rain    | High | High     | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   7 | Rain    | Low  | Normal   | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   8 | Cloudy  | High | High     | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|   9 | Cloudy  | High | Normal   | Yes    |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
|  10 | Cloudy  | Mild | Normal   | No     |
+-----+---------+------+----------+--------+
```

Given this data, what is the probability of going to beach when Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High?

I'm not talking about machine learning for now.

I apply Bayes' theorem $ P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A) P(A)}{P(B)} $.

$$
P(\textrm{Beach}\mid \textrm{Outlook}]=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High}) \\[1em]= \frac{P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High }\mid \textrm{Beach })\times P(\textrm{Beach})} {P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High})}
$$

I assume all attributes are independent, then I have

$$
=
\frac{P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}\mid \textrm{Beach })\times P(\textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High}\mid \textrm{Beach })\times P(\textrm{Beach})}{P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny})\times P(\textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High})}
$$

Plug in all values, I get
$$
\begin{align*}
=& \frac{\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{4}{10}}{\frac{4}{10}\times \frac{5}{10}} 
=  \frac{9}{8}
\end{align*}
$$

How can a probability be greater than 1?

Where did I do wrong?

**Update**

After using gunes's total probability law, I get $P=\frac{27}{31}\neq 1$.

$$
\begin{align*}
 & \frac{P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High }\mid \textrm{Beach })\times P(\textrm{Beach})}{P(\textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High})} \\[1em] 
 =& \frac{P(O=S|B)\times P(T=H\mid B)\times P(B) \tag a}{P(O=S, T=H|B)\times P(B)+P(O=S, T=H|B')\times P(B') \tag b} \\[1em] 
 =& \frac{P(O=S\mid B )P(T=H \mid B) P(B)}{P(O=S|B)P(T=H|B)P(B) +P(O=S|B')\times P(T=H|B')\times P(B') \tag a} \\[1em] 
= & \frac{\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{4}{10}}{\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{4}{10}+\frac{1}{6}\times \frac{2}{6}\times \frac{6}{10} } 
=  \frac{27}{31}
\end{align*}
$$

```
a: assume conditional independence
b: use total probability law
```

**Update 2 for Bounty**

Please show step-by-step calculation for

1. probability of going to beach when Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High
2. probability of not going to beach when Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High (do not use 1-p)
3. probability of going to beach when Temp=Low, Humidity=High
4. probability of not going to beach when Temp=Low, Humidity=High (do not use 1-p)

Comment: Ok, after assuming conditional independence, you can't find $1$ because conditional independence assumption is not true according to data. So, don't expect it to be equal to the correct probability estimated from data.

Comment: @gunes I don't get it. I believe you saw my update. Is 27/31 correct? Why conditional independence assumption is not true according to data?  How does data tell me conditional independence assumption is not true?

Comment: Because according to data `P(O=S, T=H|B) != P(O=S|B)P(T=H|B)` The former is 1/2 and the latter is 9/16

Comment: @gunes ah... ok, so given this data, can you show me what is $ P(\textrm{Beach}\mid \textrm{Outlook}=\textrm{Sunny}, \textrm{Temp}=\textrm{High} )$?

Comment: According to data, it is 1 because there are two cases where Sunny and Temp is High, and for both of them Beach is Yes.

Comment: For (1), it is the (count of Beach = True, Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High) / (count of  Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High) = 2/2 = 1. This probability calculation has nothing to do with Naive Bayes assumption of yours. The others are calculated in a similar manner. If you're unsure of the answers for 2,3,4, you can share your calculations under them, and we could check.

Comment: I would like to switch, that you guys share your calculations and I will check.

Comment: I'm afraid that is more uncommon in this forum. By the way, I think you have all the hints you need to calculate 2,3 and 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of your independence assumption, which is not true based on the data. For example,

$$P(\text{Outlook=Sunny, Temp=High}|\text{Beach})=1/2$$

because there are 4 situations where you go to Beach and in only two of them the Outlook is Sunny and Temp is High. It's the same situation for the denominator.

Comment: If independence assumption is incorrect, why can Naive Bayes classifier assume independence?

Comment: Naive bayes assumes only conditional independence. You can do so as well, but in the denominator you should write: $$P(O,T)=P(O,T|B)P(B)+P(O,T|B')P(B')$$

Comment: @Gqqnbig moreover, native Bayes is not used to calculate the probabilities, but to make classifications. For non-naive calculations, you need the exact probabilities to plug in into Bayes theorem.

Comment: @gunes what's the name of equation you are using for the denominator equations?

Comment: It's the total probability law.

Comment: By looking at the table, there are two rows matching O=S,T=H, and among them Beach are all Yes. Can I directly say P=1? What mistakes did I make?

Comment: Yes, you can. You should be obtaining the same prob. using Bayes Rule as well.

Comment: Can you calculate the probability step by step? I can hardly figure it out. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you put how you calculate to the original post, and let's figure out your mistake together?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114016/discussion-between-gqqnbig-and-gunes).